# Need a device to calculate the FFT more than 100 times per second (my scope is maxed out at 10hz)

Tags: usb, dsp, fft, processor

I'm writing some Python code which retrieves the FFT data that is generated in my Rigol DS1102E oscilloscope via its USB connection.

My trouble is that no matter what time scale I set, I get no more than 10 FFT results per second.

Are there any fast USB devices which can produce results more frequently? I was hoping to achieve at least 100 FFTs per second.

Currently my scope generates 512 bins, and my input waveforms range from 100hz to 10,000hz.

I was thinking of using a soundcard for this but was actually hoping to find a "co-processor DSP" device and let it do all the work independently of the device which Python is running on.

Due to python not being very fast and the fact that I may want to monitor multiple inputs at once, It would be difficult to use the soundcard for live FFT visualization (especially on something like a Raspberry PI)

Thanks!!

Comment: Processing is probably not the challenge - getting the data *to* a suitable processor is.  But there are various USB scopes a few of which may be capable of continuous (or frequent burst) streaming over USB.  At the really high end, an FPGA-based software defined radio may be within reconfiguration of what you want to do.  Focus more on the nature of the source data and if you need all of it, or only frequent bursts.

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to do? Assuming your signals of interest are within the frequency range you specified, and your dynamic range isn't too extreme, using a soundcard + a computer is almost certainly going to be the most straightforward and inexpensive option.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I was hoping to one day sit down with a Cyclone or Spartan and give FPGA a try. But I am unsure if I could properly implement the functions for processing the spectral analysis of digital audio data - much less what I would need in regards to hardware. Any suggestions on some good chipsets, proto-boards or IPs would be very useful.

Comment: @ConnorWolf the reason I would like to use an external "co-processor" is because I can add many channels without slowing down the execution time of the Python/SciPy code by much (I hope). And it would be more appropriate for a system using slow CPUs like a raspberry pi

Comment: In general, if you don't **know** you need an FPGA, you probably don't *actually* need an FPGA. And for smaller FFTs, simply adding *another* raspberry PI is going to be far more expedient (and cheap) then a "dedicated co-processor", which might very well just be the same CPU as the Pi. There is really nothing "breadboardable" that will get you anywhere near the $/MIPS like the Pi.

Comment: Anyways, if you're on a big platform like a PC, the solution is basically [use FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) ([python lib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyFFTW)). You'd need a MASSIVE, hugely expensive FPGA system to get performance similar to a modern desktop CPU. More or less, unless you have **hard** real-time requirements (and if you're using python, you don't), going to a FPGA is probably a waste of energy.

Comment: To be clear, this would make a fine excuse to *learn* FPGA stuff, but don't expect that it'll be better then just a big ARM or x86 system.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Holy cow, you gave me an idea just now! like you said, just add a bunch of raspberry PIs, and all their job is to do nothing more than calculate the FFTs (using C++) and send the results off to the python GUI machine. its an easy to modify, very scalable, low overhead approach. and it's inexpensive!

Comment: I think you are overestimating the FFT overhead. Assuming you're desktop isn't an ancient pentium 2 or something, an external pre-processing step is really just silly. Some of the stuff I do at work involves realtime 8Kpt FFTs 250+ times/second, which is trivially done on any modern desktop CPU.

Comment: would the Raspberry PI 2 (or any ARM quad core) have enough power to generate this kind of spectral analysis at 100 times/second if programmed in pure C++??

Comment: Almost certainly. Use [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) unless GPL is completely unacceptable. (Edit: FFTW now has first-party ARM support).

Comment: [KISSfft](http://kissfft.sourceforge.net/) is a reasonable alternative if you can't use GPL, though not as performant (I use FFTW and kissfft at work. They're both quite easy to integrate).

Comment: I guess the starting point is to determine how fast is your 512-point FFT on your processor. Is it totally integer, or uses floating point?

Comment: @AliChen Good point, as I recall the scope sends a sequence of 512 data bytes within a frame, so each FFT bin is an integer 0-255

Comment: Cripes, I used to do 1024-pt complex-in, complex-out FFT in 3 ms on a 1991-date ADSP-2111 and faster still on the ADSP-2181 when I got those a few years later. 16-bit ADC data and the core only running at about 40 MHz. A 4-core ODROID-C2, 2GHz, cost about the same as a Pi and will run rings around it I think. If going that way.

Comment: Python is not the fastest language but it is not necessarily very slow. Especially there have to be math libraries for python (but not written in python) that have optimized FFT.

Answer (score 1):

> my input waveforms range from 100hz to 10,000hz.

Seriously, that means (by Nyquist) that a sampling rate of 20 kHz is sufficient – you probably want to oversample a bit, but everything above 40 kHz is luxury.

In other words, this is best soundcard-territory.

Get a cheap (<10$) USB sound card, remove the coupling capacitors from the microphone input, and use some kind of of adjustable opamp-based amplifier to get your input signal into the Soundcard's range. Done.

> It would be difficult to use the soundcard for live FFT visualization (especially on something like a Raspberry PI)

You're making wrong assumptions here!

Processing this amount of data is definitely not a problem on anything faster than the cheapest pocket calculators. A raspberry Pi, a laptop, a PC or a smartphone will definitely do. Really, the effort of doing an FFT on this amount of samples is thoroughly ridiculously small. Decoding an MP3 is far more tasking for any computer (fun fact: MP3 requires an operation pretty similar to the FFT).

Don't worry about Python slowing you down: No Python library I know does the FFT in python itself, but rely on FFTpack or FFTw (numpy, for example). You can do such short FFTs (i.e. "less than a hundred thousand bins") at sampling rates of multiple Megasamples per second on a normal PC, so don't worry about the workload posed by the FFT. Seriously, 100+ transforms of length 1024 per second? More like 1 Million transforms per second, in my [experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916536/is-there-a-constant-time-algorithm-for-generating-a-bandlimited-sawtooth/32931019#32931019). I can't stop wondering why people even think that's hard, but watch full-screen MPEG4-encoded videos at the same time on all of their devices.

To demonstrate how easy this is: I [wrote an answer a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213443/gnu-radio-use-sound-output-as-input-source/32231041#32231041) that demonstrates how to visualize audio data. If you don't do the whole loopback dance, but just select your soundcard as source, you're done and have your FFT'ing visualization:

[image: Visualization using GNU Radio]

I also wrote a minimal firmware a while back (can't find it, sorry) that used a 6$ Tiva-C ARM evalboard to convert and send samples to a PC at up to 200kS/s over USB as bulk transfers. You'd have to write your own userland "driver" software to talk to such a device, but it'd work, too. But there's not much winnage in doing so compared to buying a sound card, unless you'll need to use such a microcontroller anyway, e.g. to control something else.